# How can I connect to a postgres database using php via an open ssh tunnel?

Tags: php, postgresql, ssh

I need to connect to a postgres database on a remote server using PHP. I've opened an SSH tunnel on the local machine, local port 8000. The tunnel seems to work fine.

The problem arises when I attempt to connect to the db with PHP. The following code:

```
$ConnectionString = "host=127.0.0.1:8000  user=username password=passphrase dbname=databasename sslmode=require port=5432";
pg_connect($ConnectionString);
```

produces the following error:

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not translate host name "127.0.0.1:8000" to address: Unknown host in [path]\mappage.php on line 22
Not connected
```

How, then, can I open a database connection via SSH?

For what it's worth, I can connect to the remote PostgreSQL database with PGAdmin using SSH.

Answer (score 0):

As written [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.pg-connect.php) it should be:

```
$ConnectionString = "host=127.0.0.1 port=8000  user=username password=passphrase dbname=databasename sslmode=require";
```

You had port twice and once incorrectly.

Comment: Unfortunately it just causes the code to produce the following error: `Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SSL error: unknown protocol in [path]\mappage.php on line 22
Not connected :`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set up the tunnel, you connect to your database via 127.0.0.1. e.g. (MySQL Example):

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8000:127.0.0.1:5432 sshuser@example.com
```

After that the connection parameters for my database are:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1 (localhost would try to connect to socket)
Port: 8000
User: username
Pass: passphrase
```